# elastic4s refresh index immediately is not refreshing the index properly

Tags: elastic4s

I am using elastic4s for all the elasticsearch operations.

I am trying to test an application in the docker containers (testconatiners)

The test will index 3 documents and retrieves them again and verify. The third document is always null while retrieving. I used a debug point in the code and realised if I wait for couple of seconds before retrieving the document, it retrieves it properly.

Here is the sample code for indexing.

```
implicit val caseClassNameEncoder: Encoder[CaseClassName] = Encoder.forProduct7(
      "field_1", "field_2", "field_3", "field_4", "field_5", "field_6", "field_7"
    )(u => (u.field_1.format(dateTimeWithZoneFormatter), u.field_2, u.field_3, u.field_4, u.field_5, u.field_6, u.field_7))
    client.execute {
      indexInto(writeAlias).id(caseClassName.id.toString).doc(caseClassName.asJson).refreshImmediately
    }
```

I just added waiting time 1 second, the test is success. How do I deal with it?